# Redirect Server Aliases to Server Name Over HTTPS on Apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, httpd.conf

I have been looking around for an answer to my problem for a while and have read various other answers without coming across one that works for me.

The problem I am trying to solve involves redirecting access to a WordPress site installed on an Apache server. The WordPress site is one of many installed as part of a WordPress Network installation and the site is setup on the domain https://www.mysite1.co.uk.

It is also necessary to access the site using a number of server aliases, which are to be redirected to the root domain. I have created the additional domains as server aliases in the Apache configuration, and have set redirects to ensure that if one of the aliases is entered then it should be redirected to the root domain.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite1.co.uk
    ServerAlias mysite1.co.uk www.mysite2.co.uk mysite2.co.uk
    ...

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)\.?$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite1.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.mysite1.co.uk
    ServerAlias mysite1.co.uk www.mysite2.co.uk mysite2.co.uk
    ...

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)\.?$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite1.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "certs/mysite1.co.uk.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "certs/mysite1.co.uk.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration works whenever the user enters one of the aliases using http, they are redirected to https://www.mysite1.co.uk/. However, if they enter the aliases using https, instead of being redirected to https://www.mysite1.co.uk/,  they are not being redirected at all.

Have I missed something in the configuration, or do I need to separate the https configuration and add the aliases into their own virtual host to do the redirect.
The sites are hosted on CentOS 7.9.2009 and running Apache 2.4.6.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it correctly, you're trying to redirect every known domain reaching your apache to just one domain and when the connection comes as HTTP you want to redirect it to HTTPS.

To keep the configuration simple, I would create 3 different virtual hosts:

The first one will listen on http and include every domain you want to redirect (including the main one becuase it's listening on http). This virtualhost will redirect everything to the main domain over https:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName main.site.com
   ServerAlias mysite.example.com
   ServerAlias another.site.com
   Redirect permanent / https://main.site.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

The second one will listen on https port and includes all the domains but the main one and redirect it to your primary domain (it's like the previous one except it doesn't include the main domain)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   ServerAlias another.site.com
   Redirect permanent / https://main.site.com/
   
   ...
   SSLEngine On
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

In the end, the main one will just listen on https and will include only the main domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName main.site.com
   
   ...
   SSLEngine On
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

This way, the only virtualhost requiring configuretiona (document root, locations, etc.) is the last one.